# OpenAcc + Cython not working

Tags: python, c, cython, openacc

I have some C++ code that I'd like to accelerate using OpenACC. I call the C++ from python using cython, but when I add OpenACC pragmas it doesn't seem to work. I tried a simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 2000000000

#define vl 1024

int main(void) {

  double pi = 0.0f;
  long long i;

  #pragma acc parallel vector_length(vl) 
  #pragma acc loop reduction(+:pi)
  for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    double t= (double)((i+0.5)/N);
    pi +=4.0/(1.0+t*t);
  }

  printf("pi=%11.10f\n",pi/N);

  return 0;

}
```

When compiling this with `gcc pi.c -fopenacc -foffload=nvptx-none -foffload="-O3" -O3 -o gpu.x` it works perfectly.

I then tried wrapping this in cython with a very simple `.pyx` file:

```
cdef extern from "pi.c":
    int main()


def func():
    return main()
```

My `setup.py` file looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [Extension(name="cpi",
                        sources=["cpi.pyx"],
                        extra_compile_args=["-O3", "-fopenacc", "-foffload=nvptx-none"],
                        extra_link_args=["-lgomp", "-fno-lto"],
                        language="c")]

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(extensions))
```

Building with `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` works but when I try to call the function from python I get an error: "libgomp: target function wasn't mapped"

When I try building without the `-fno-lto` flag I get the error "ImportError: ....so: undefined symbol: __offload_func_table" after calling it in python.

I haven't found anything similar on the internet...

Comment: `main` has a special meaning in C. I would try calling it something else when you call it from Cython.

Comment: I've tried renaming it, same error. I also get the same error for other C++ code I tried, I don't think it's anything special to this code, but more likely some wrong compiler option...

Comment: Try to add `"-fopenacc", "-foffload=nvptx-none"` `to extra_link_args` otherwise the linker doesn't know that openacc is needed. Run your gcc command in verbose mode `-v` to see what really happens and compare to build_ext run with `-v`.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I think I'm actually stupid... I thought that I tried every combination of compile_args and link_args, but it seems I just forgot to add both `-fopenacc` and `-foffload=nvptx-none` to `extra_link_args`...